# Homebrew: how to enable preprocessor defines?

Tags: build, homebrew

Some libraries have conditional builds enabled by preprocessor defines, say, `#ifdef ENABLE_THIS_FEATURE`. How do we enable features like this  with Homebrew?

With `vcpkg`, we could tweak CMake through `vcpkg` facilities. It's unclear to me how to do so with Homebrew.